# Drop down option selection in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

```
<select id="PRMT_SV_N0x29a524c0x0x2c68e47c_NS_" class="clsSelectControl pv" aria- 
 multiselectable="false" aria-invalid="false" style="width: 5cm;" xpath="1">

<option value="1" 
 dv="Transactions Only">&nbsp;Transactions&nbsp;Only</option>

<option 
 value="2" dv="Few Transactions Only">&nbsp;Transactions&nbsp;Only</option><option value="3" 
 dv="All Transactions">All&nbsp;Transactions</option>

</select>
```

I have HTML as above and it is drop down list. I have to click on element so I can see all three options and pick last option Value =3. Below is the code I have and it's not working or throwing any error. It's work to the part by clicking the element, but is not selecting the option.

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/select[1]').click()

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/select[1]'))
select.select_by_value('3')
```

Comment: please share the error you are getting

Answer (score 2):

To select an element from a html-select menu you have to use the `select` Class and no need to click on element to select the drop-down value.

**Code:**

```
select= Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[contains(@class,'clsSelectControl')]'))
select.select_by_value(3)
```

**Imports**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

Comment: It's not working

Comment: What error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime `Select` class do not work properly, in those cases we would need JS intervention.

Please try this :

```
index = '3'
driver.execute_script(f"return document.querySelector('select.clsSelectControl.pv').selectedIndex = {index}")
```